# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin - timeout logout

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, sfdoctrineguard

i use Symfony 1.4 + sfDoctrineGuardUser. I have timeout set. This working good. User is logout, but SESSION for user isn't clear. Where i can this set?

additionally i would like without refresh the page, for example every 15 minutes check value in database and send new query to DB.

Answer (score 0):

why would you clear the whole session? the session isn't only used for the login; there are other things like the current language and so on stored…

the check for new values in the DB you can easily achieve with jquery (timers and $.ajax)

Comment: because in session i have USERID. user is logout, but in session is his ID

Comment: This shouldn't bother you. Usualy you check if `$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated()` and this will return false after logout.